# When Mongoose uses "mongodb://" in the connection string, is mongodb:// a protocol?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is "mongodb://" a protocol or is just a string that is parsed by the script? This code below is taken from Mongoose's getting started [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/).

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
```

Comment: Well effectively yes, by the representation that is the intention. It is not likely to be recognized as such by many URI parsing libraries though. What is the actual point of the question that you need to know this for?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a protocol, it's a prefix in a connection string that defines that the string is in the standard connection format.

The [Java driver documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClientURI.html) has a nice explanation for every part of the MongoDB URI.

Comment: From [URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) 'URI schemes are frequently and incorrectly referred to as "protocols",' and then '<scheme name> : <hierarchical part> [ ? <query> ] [ # <fragment> ]'